# Usecase diagram Database Actor Logo?

Tags: uml

I have build a program which uses an external database. So I need to add that as an Actor to the Use Case Diagram. Since I am adding Database as an actor, Which is the best way to represent it (by using a matchstick human icon or a database icon or something else) ??

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are modeling business, a database is not really an actor. Only if you model technical domains it will be an actor.

As per UML spec on p. 640:

> An Actor is represented by a “stick man” icon with the name of the Actor in the vicinity (usually above or below) the icon, as illustrated by the example in Figure 18.6.
>
> An Actor may also be shown as a Classifier rectangle with the keyword «actor», with the usual notation for all compartments, as illustrated by the example in Figure 18.7.
>
> Other icons that convey the kind of Actor may also be used to denote an Actor, such as using a separate icon for non- human Actors, as illustrated by the example in Figure 18.8.

Answer (score 1):

According to specification a sticky figure is the basic way of presenting actor and it can be use for any kind of actors including other systems. You can add a stereotype (e.g. <>) to indicate it's a system rather than a person.

Specification allows you also to use other kind of icons to represent specific actors, so you can use e.g. a sticky figure with a head formed into rectangle rather than circle to indicate a system.

**Disclaimer**: The rest is opinion based

I don't thing there is such thing as the best method to show that. I would avoid concentrating if this additional actor is a database or some other kind of a system. Just indicate it is a system. It might change over time for example.

As a rule of thumb - use such elements that will be readable for other users of your diagram.

Comment: Ok. That means is it possible to declare "Database" at the bottom of the sticky figure and "<<System>>" at the top of the sticky figure?  (I am using Xampp to use the MySQL database. Does that mean it is a system)?

Comment: Before I answer that - is MySQL part of your system responsible for storing the data or are you retrieving data from some other system's database? If it is a part of your system, handling your data, it's not a separate actor at all. Elements of modelled system aren't actors at all, only entities external to the system can become actors.

Comment: Hmmm.. I have a database in MySql. The data is stored at there (so couldn't it be a seperate entity?). Software runs in Java Virtual Environment. So software is separate from the database. Is this correct ?

Note:Database and Software is running on my local computer. But the software and database are two different platforms !!

Comment: Being separate platforms doesn't mean they don't pose a single system. Moreover they don't even have to be at the same machine. That's what multilayer system concept is for. Of course you'll neither build nor embed database engine in your system, you're going to use an existing solution and interface it (quite natively by the way). The database of your system even if located in a cloud somewhere in the Internet is part of your system and thus isn't an actor. To model those details you can use a deployment diagram.